# Istio with Elastic Stack for Observability

Tags: microservices, elastic-stack, istio, jaeger, servicemesh

I am currently using Istio as service mesh with Kubernetes. I want to implement observability infrastructure with Elastic Stack , I know Istio is supported for jaeger and Prometheus, But I have to capture distributed tracing and matrices via Elastic stack. Can some one tell me how to export traces and matrices to ELK stack via Istio. Reference implementation (or high-level diagram) is highly appreciated

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Perhaps the following links can help for Istio-Prometheus metrics (scraping via federation) : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-prometheus-collector.html and https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/observability/#using-prometheus-for-production-scale-monitoring

Comment: Yes these are very useful, i have already gone through , Have you got implemented the APM with ELK stack via istio ?